# Checkbox en laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, mvc, checkbox, laravel-livewire

Alguien conocera alguna forma de implementar un checkbox en un buscador de consultas es decir yo busco datos de una base de datos existentes y los inserto en otra base de datos pero necesito seleccionar solo los registros que necesito Estoy utilizando Laravel Livewire
En la imagen hago una consulta de unas facturas las cuales quiero añadir 1 o varias pero no quiero añadir todas cabe recalcar que cada factura puede contener varios productos entonces por lo mismo se pueden ver que son repetitivas pero es la misma factura con diferentes productos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Traits\FindFactura;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\viewfacturaa;
class RecepcionFactura extends Component
{
    protected $listeners = ['verModalFactura'];

  use findFactura;
  public $recepcion;
  public $viewfacturaa = [];
  public $listRecepcion = [];
  public $seleccion = [];
  public $modal = false;





    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.recepcion-factura');
    }

    public function saveResults()
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $fecha_oc = "";
            $listRecepcion = $this->findFactura($this->recepcion);
            foreach ($listRecepcion as $item) {

                $item->fecha_oc = $fecha_oc;
                $this->createdNewRecepcion($item);
            }
            DB::commit();
            $this->emit('render');
            $this->cerrarModalRecepcion();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
        }
    }


    public function verModalFactura()
    {
        $this->modal = true;
    }
    public function cerrarModalFactura()
    {
        $this->recepcion = null;
        $this->listRecepcion = [];
        $this->modal = false;
    }
    public function find()
    {
        $this->listRecepcion = $this->findFactura($this->recepcion);



    }
}
```

Vista:

```
 <div>
        @if ($modal)

            <div class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto ease-out duration-400">
                <div class="flex justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center  sm:p-0">

                    <div class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity">
                        <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
                    </div>

                    <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen"></span>

                    <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-xl sm:w-full"
                        role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-headline">
                        <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                            <label form="recepcion" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Facturas:</label>



                            <div class="inline-flex w-full">
                                <input name="recepcion" type="text"
                                    class="form-control focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" wire:model.lazy="recepcion"
                                    autocomplete="off">
                                &nbsp;
                                <button wire:click="find()"  class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
                            </div>
                            @if (count($listRecepcion) > 0)
                                <button wire:click="saveResults()" class="mt-2 btn btn-success w-full">Guardar
                                    Resultados</button>
                            @endif

                            <button wire:click="cerrarModalFactura()"
                                class="mt-2 btn btn-secondary w-full">Cancelar</button>

                            @if (count($listRecepcion) > 0)
                                <table class="w-full mt-4">
                                    <thead class="bg-blue-900 text-white">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">Seleccion</th>
                                            <th class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">Factura</th>
                                            <th class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">Cliente</th>
                                            <th class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">Fecha</th>
                                            <th class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">Vendedor</th>
                                            <th class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">Producto</th>
                                            <th class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">Descripcion del producto</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($listRecepcion as $r)
                                            <tr>

                                              <td class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">
                                              <input wire:model="seleccion.{{$r->PRODUCTO}}" type="checkbox" value="{{ $r->PRODUCTO }}" ></td>

                                                <td class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">{{ $r->FACTURA }}</td>
                                                <td class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">{{ $r->DENOMINACION_SOCIAL }}</td>
                                                <td class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">{{ $r->FECHA }}</td>
                                                <td class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">{{ $r->NOMBRE_COMPLETO }}</td>
                                                <td class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">{{ $r->PRODUCTO }}</td>
                                                <td class="border px-2 py-2 text-xs">{{ $r->DESCRIPCION_FACTURA }}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            @else
                                <br>
                                @if (gettype($listRecepcion) == 'object')
                                    <span class="text-red-600 text-bold">No se encontraron resultados.</span>
                                @endif
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
```

Comment: Posiblemente esto te oriente un poco más https://m1000.medium.com/manejo-de-checkboxes-con-laravel-livewire-c4350317109c